# Node.js, Outgoing request from Heroku to OVH, error 503

Tags: node.js, heroku, request, ovh

I want to make an outgoing request from my Heroku server to a server on OVH. Unfortunately Heroku closes my request and returns a 503 status. How can I fix that?

[image: log]

Answer (score 0):

@nickdbush the href is "http://static.lookaforeigner.com/upload.php" so I don't understand.

- It works: local -> "http://static.lookaforeigner.com/upload.php"
- It doesn't work: heroku -> "http://static.lookaforeigner.com/upload.php"

Comment: Sorry, I was ready the hostname and not looking at the pathname as well. It works for me - it says ```Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.```

Comment: Then there must be no way to POST ```/upload.php```. When you request it from your browser it GETs and that works but your request from Heroku is making a POST request which fails. Maybe?

Comment: Exactly !! Why heroku close POST request ? How fix that ? Because POST request from my local node.js app works.

Comment: Could it be a problem with your server code? Could we see some of it?